# Listbox appears through modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, listbox, transparency, modalpopupextender

I have a base page in which i have a listbox.
The base page is also having a modal popup extender.
When the modal popup extender appears over listbox, the listbox appears through modal poup.
That is, only for listbox, the popup extender becomes transparent.

What shud I do for this?

Comment: If your modal popup extender has a CssClass property, maybe create some css to and set the Z-Index:999; or something like that.

Comment: 1. The code is in my client-machine..i can not copy the same.
2. currently my z-index value is 10000. But no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that, since listboxes/dropdowns are windows controls, they will always appear over the modal popup.

I haven't tested this, but your best bet may be to write some code in the button click handler that launches the popup and either diable or hide the offending control.